# How tightly can a starship turn while at warp?

Tags: star-trek

We know that starships can change directions, turn, bank and dogfight at warp speeds. This is visually demonstrated on the Enterprise's view screen in "The Wounded" TNG 4x12, when the Nebula Class starship Phoenix (captained by Starfleet Captain Benjamin Maxwell) and 'flying' at warp in close formation with the escort ship Enterprise, suddenly changes course and banks hard right to pursue a Cardassian ship.

[image]

The question is; How tightly can they turn? As example; can they orbit a planet at warp speed?

Another example:

Picard, Data, Yar and Troi enter the battle bridge, with Chief Miles O'Brien manning the conn. First, Picard orders that Yar fire photon torpedoes towards the object. Yar complies and the torpedoes are away. Shortly after, Picard orders that the countdown to saucer separation begin. Data counts down, and the ship separates while at warp. The stardrive section turns around and heads towards a confrontation with Q.

http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Encounter_at_Farpoint_(episode)

Comment: VOY says quite clearly they can't turn (at least much) at warp, I believe it was Tom Paris quoting one of his academy professors saying "Faster than light, no left or right." Though given the shows' consistency with respect to technology, it could just have been for that episode.

Comment: @Kevin I saw that. It seems to be a singular ST episode with that philosophy/restriction. In the very first TNG episode, "Encounter at Farpoint" TNG 1x1, the Enterprise makes a hard 180 degree turn at high warp to go back and confront an entity we know as 'Q'.

Comment: I wonder how quickly a ship can drop out of and get back into warp.  Could you build something like a clutch that briefly disengages the drive and then allows you to use another drive to change your vector, then re-engage the warp drive?

Comment: There are numerous other places where it appears a ship must drop to sublight to turn.  Star Trek is famous for inconsistency in technical aspects.

Comment: @BBlake- "inconsistency in technical aspects"? It seems so in this case. If the dialogue 'says' it can't be done, all evidence to the contrary considering the Enterprise-D separated the saucer section and executed a tight 180 degree turn at warp 9.5, what then is considered 'canon' in this regard?

Comment: @Zoredache Yes, I believe it was Janeway that offered to do that as a way not to accidentally scan a very secretive civilization whose space they had to cross..  Or Paris when they had to cross a very tight path in dangerous space?  Those were two different episodes, and I _think_ it was mentioned in one of them...

Comment: @Kevin -Some quick math; Based on the known length of the Enterprise and the turn visuals shown on screen when they performed that tight 180° turn to go back and confront 'Q' (TNG 1x1, "Encounter at Farpoint"), indicates a demonstrated turn radius of approximately 13,000 meters at warp 9.5.

Comment: *Star Trek IV: The Voyage Home* shows the crew piloting their Klingon ship around the sun at warp (in order to achieve the time travel plot device). It's unclear just how tight the turn is, but it's clearly on the edge of capability.

Comment: @Kevin I also remember that, but it is directly contradictory with various comments made by helmsman/navigators in other shows. Specifically, in Star Trek: Discovery, it showed _in_ the viewscreen how the warp "tunnel" or bubble curved to the left or right as the Discovery turned in one of those directions. And they were really at warp. And in TNG, they talk about course alterations all the time, so it must be that you _can_ change course at warp.

Answer (score 9):

It would not be possible to orbit a planet at warp speed, due to the dangers of producing FTL warp fields in large gravity wells.

The enterprise had to reverse power (slow down or drop out of warp) to allow the saucer to escape after separating.  there were no streaking stars in the turning shot suggesting the ship was at a sublight, though high speed.

"at the moment of separation, we will reverse power just enough to allow your saucer section to get out ahead and clear of us" - Picard, Encounter at Farpoint.

The TNG Technical Manual pages 95 and 96, state that changes in direction can be accomplished by varying the timing of the injectors, creating some differences in the warp fields produced by each nacelle.  But also states that a loss of one or both nacelles at warp would tear the ship apart.  Similar to turning a ship with two propellers by making one go faster than the other, it puts enormous strain on the hull.  This suggests a limit to the warp turn speed.

Voyager's turning circle was clearly larger than the distance between two vacuoles, that's why the ship had to stop and turn.  Turning at warp is not impossible, but not recommended.  "When possible try to maintain a linear trajectory".  Due to the speed and energy involved any unbalanced forces could be catastrophic.  "faster than light, no left or right" is a good rule of thumb, though there are exceptions.

Comment: It wouldn't be possible to orbit a planet at warp speed because orbit is not maintained by the ship's engines. Orbit is essentially falling towards the planet and missing it constantly because of forward momentum. If a ship was moving faster than light, it'd need to be inside the event horizon of a black hole for there to be enough gravity to pull the ship around enough to encircle it instead of the ship simply flying off.

Comment: Also, if the ship was going fast enough in low orbit, it would explode from the drag or cause a huge vacuum if it's even possible for the ship to survive.

Answer (score 0):

There is no canonical answer beyond, "Whatever the writers of a given episode write." There is simply no consistency in what can and cannot be done while traveling at warp speeds.

Comment: Actually you'll find that the majority of episodes conform to the various "writer's guides" given to scriptwriters.

Comment: I think they try very hard to stay consistent with established canon, though they do slip up from time to time.

Answer (score -3):

Warp Maneuvering
From the earliest days of warp flight the primary rule has always been, "Faster than light, no left or right."
The truth is that making a Yaw (Port or Starboard) maneuvers at warp has always been possible - and with single-piece warp coils it is all that was possible - as it involves little more than applying a bit more energy to one nacelle or the other.  The more energy applied, the greater the angular deviation; the greater the deviation, the greater the likelihood of a warp field imbalance and collapse, not to mention possible damage to the warp coils from too much energy or structural damage during a field collapse.
So the primary reason for the old rule is safety.

From the Phoenix to the very early 24th century only Yaw and Roll maneuvers were possible at warp, Roll being a function of the RCS thrusters and having no effect on the overall course of the ship, even early 4 nacelle designs followed the rule due to the limitations of warp control software.
Come Generation 4 warp systems, like those of the Galaxy class, and the use of the split toroid warp coils, Pitch maneuvers were added to the mix; applying more energy to the upper or lower half of the toroid will allow a starship some limited +/- Z axis maneuvers during warp flight.

It must be noted that during any of these limited maneuver schemes, the starship will not actually change its directional orientation or bank with the turn, it will simply slide in the direction chosen, looking much like an automobile making slow, easy lane changes on a freeway.

Comment: Other than the initial quote from an episode of Voyager, as provided in a comment by @Kevin on the original answer, do you have any references or citations for any of these claims?

Comment: This answer seems to largely consist of fan-fiction.

Comment: In the TOS "Elaan of Troyius" the Enterprise was crippled by someone rigging the matter/antimatter reactor to blow up if they went into warp and were fighting a Klingon vessel. After the reactor was fixed they lured the Klingon ship closer and Kirk gave the order to pivot at warp 2 from sub light speed and sent three torpedoes at the Klingon ship. It doesn't show how wide of an arc they pivoted on. I just remember they did it. One of my favorite episodes.

Comment: First of all, there is no source mentioned. Second of all, they showed in Star Trek: Discovery that helmsman Keyla Detmer altered course _during warp_--the warp bubble/tunnel actually curved/bent right or left, because the Discovery went right or left.